# How to restrict the datepicker to inherit the CSS related to table?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datepicker

I have two CSS files related to Table and one css for datepicker .But the patepicker is acccessing the properties of table css.So my question is how to restrict the datepicker to access the table CSS.

Answer (score 0):

In your table file use :not Selector to select all table elements except for de Datepiker tab

exp:

```
 table:not(.Datepiker) {
    //table style here excep Datepiker
    }
 table:not(.Datepiker) tr {
    //table style here excep Datepiker
    }
```

```css
  tablestyle.css
------------------
@charset "utf-8";
table:not(.ui-datepicker) {
font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
font-size: 8pt;
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse:collapse;
border-spacing:5px;
}

table:not(.ui-datepicker-calendar) tr:nth-child(odd){
//background:#b8d1f3;
background:rgb(233,237,244);
}
table:not(.ui-datepicker-calendar) tr:nth-child(even){
//background:#dae5f4;   
background:rgb(211,220,232)
}
table:not(.ui-datepicker-calendar) th{
//background:#666;
background:rgb(92,133,179);
color:white;
font-weight: bold;
text-decoration: underline;
}
table:not(.ui-datepicker-calendar) td { 
padding: 5px; 
font-size: 9pt;
border: 1px solid green;
}
table:not(.ui-datepicker-calendar):hover { //outline: 2px dashed #0090D2;}

table:not(.ui-datepicker) input[type='text']{
width:120px;
}

}




tablestyleresponsive.css
----------------------------------
@media  only screen and (max-width: 760px),
(min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px)  {

    /* Force table to not be like tables anymore */
    table, thead, tbody, th, td, tr {
        display: block;
    }

    /* Hide table headers (but not display: none;, for accessibility) */
    table:not(.ui-datepicker-calendar) thead tr, th {
        position: absolute;
        top: -9999px;
        left: -9999px;
    }

    table:not(.ui-datepicker-calendar) tr { border: 1px solid #ccc; }

    table:not(.ui-datepicker-calendar) td {
        /* Behave  like a "row" */
        border: none;
        border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 50%;
    }

    table:not(.ui-datepicker-calendar) td:before {          
        position: absolute;         
        //top: 4px;         
        left: 4px;
        //width: 45%;
        padding-right: 10px;
        white-space: nowrap;
    }

    /* Label the data*/
    #Phone td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Type"; }
    #Phone td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Country"; }
    #Phone td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Phone"; }
    #Phone td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Preferred"; }
    #Phone td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Add/Delete"; }

    #Major td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Preferred"; }
    #Major td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Major"; }
    #Major td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Concentration"; }
    #Major td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Status"; }

    #Education thead:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "#Educational Information"; }
    #Education td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "School Code"; }
    #Education td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "School Name"; }
    #Education td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "High school Average"; }
    #Education td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "GPA Type"; }
    #Education td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "CGPA"; }
    #Education td:nth-of-type(6):before { content: "Accdemic Level"; }
    #Education td:nth-of-type(7):before { content: "Degree"; }
    #Education td:nth-of-type(8):before { content: "Degree Date"; }
    #Education td:nth-of-type(9):before { content: "Transcript Date"; }
    #Education td:nth-of-type(10):before { content: "Add/Delete"; }

    #Test td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Preference"; }
    #Test td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Major"; }
    #Test td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Concentration"; }
    #Test td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Status"; }
    #Test td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "Add/Delete"; }

    #Employee td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Job_title"; }
    #Employee td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Employer"; }
    #Employee td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "From"; }
    #Employee td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "To"; }
    #Employee td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "Add/Delete"; }

    #Emergency_Contact td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Relationship"; }
    #Emergency_Contact td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "First Name"; }
    #Emergency_Contact td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Last Name"; }
    #Emergency_Contact td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Phone"; }
    #Emergency_Contact td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "Email Id"; }
    #Emergency_Contact td:nth-of-type(6):before { content: "Consent"; }
    #Emergency_Contact td:nth-of-type(7):before { content: "Working/Student"; }
    #Emergency_Contact td:nth-of-type(8):before { content: "Employee/Student ID"; }
    #Emergency_Contact td:nth-of-type(9):before { content: "Add/Delete"; }

    #Personal_document td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Attachment type"; }
    #Personal_document td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "Attached File"; }
    #Personal_document td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "View"; }
    #Personal_document td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Add Attachment"; }
    #Personal_document td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "Accepted"; }
    #Personal_document td:nth-of-type(6):before { content: "Rejection Reason"; }

    #Accademic_Transcripts td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Attached File"; }
    #Accademic_Transcripts td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "View"; }
    #Accademic_Transcripts td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Add Attachment"; }
    #Accademic_Transcripts td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Accepted"; }
    #Accademic_Transcripts td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "Rejection Reason"; }
    #Accademic_Transcripts td:nth-of-type(6):before { content: "Add/Delete"; }

    #Accademic_Documents td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Attached File"; }
    #Accademic_Documents td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "View"; }
    #Accademic_Documents td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Add Attachment"; }
    #Accademic_Documents td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Accepted"; }
    #Accademic_Documents td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "Rejection Reason"; }
    #Accademic_Documents td:nth-of-type(6):before { content: "Add/Delete"; }

    #Other_Document td:nth-of-type(1):before { content: "Attached File"; }
    #Other_Document td:nth-of-type(2):before { content: "View"; }
    #Other_Document td:nth-of-type(3):before { content: "Add Attachment"; }
    #Other_Document td:nth-of-type(4):before { content: "Accepted"; }
    #Other_Document td:nth-of-type(5):before { content: "Rejection Reason"; }
    #Other_Document td:nth-of-type(6):before { content: "Add/Delete"; }

}

/* Smartphones (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 480px) {
    body {
        padding: 0;
        margin: 0;
        width: 320px; }
    }

/* iPads (portrait and landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen and (min-device-width: 768px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) {
    body {
        //width: 495px;
    }
}



#content {
width: auto;
float: left;
}

#middle {
width: auto; /* Account for margins + border values */
float: left;
}

#sidebar {
width: auto;
float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
 <title>Website</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/custom_style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/tableStyle.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/tableStyleResponsive.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">    
    <!-- Required For date picker -->   
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>   
    
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script> 
 
    <!-- Required For Validation--> 
    <script src="JS/Basic.validation.js"></script> 
    
    <!-- Required For Table Responsive-->
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
    <!-- Date Picker -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 
 <!-- Date Picker JS And CSS  -->
 <style>
    #ui-datepicker-div { font-size: 12px; } 
    #datepicker{}
    </style>
    <script>
    $(function() {
 $("#dob").datepicker({
    //showOn: both - datepicker will appear clicking the input box as well as the calendar icon
    //showOn: button - datepicker will appear only on clicking the calendar icon
    showOn: 'button',
    //you can use your local path also eg. buttonImage: 'images/x_office_calendar.png'
    buttonImage: 'http://theonlytutorials.com/demo/x_office_calendar.png',
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    duration: 'fast',
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });
    $("#Issue_date").datepicker({
    //showOn: both - datepicker will appear clicking the input box as well as the calendar icon
    //showOn: button - datepicker will appear only on clicking the calendar icon
    showOn: 'button',
    //you can use your local path also eg. buttonImage: 'images/x_office_calendar.png'
    buttonImage: 'http://theonlytutorials.com/demo/x_office_calendar.png',
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    duration: 'fast',
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });
    $("#Passport_expiry_date").datepicker({
    //showOn: both - datepicker will appear clicking the input box as well as the calendar icon
    //showOn: button - datepicker will appear only on clicking the calendar icon
    showOn: 'button',
    //you can use your local path also eg. buttonImage: 'images/x_office_calendar.png'
    buttonImage: 'http://theonlytutorials.com/demo/x_office_calendar.png',
    buttonImageOnly: true,
    changeMonth: true,
    changeYear: true,
    duration: 'fast',
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy'
    });

    });
  </script> 
  <!--<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
 $("input.add").live('click', function() {
  var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
  var $clone = $tr.clone();
  $clone.find(':text').val('');
  $tr.after($clone);
    });
 $("input.delete").live('click',function(){
         if(document.getElementById('phone').getElementsByTagName("tr").length!=3);{
         var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');  
   $tr.remove(); 
   return false;
   }  
 });
});   
</script> -->
</head>
 <!-- Body Started-->
    <body>
    <form name="Basicinfo" id="Basicinfo" method="post" action="Basic.html">
    <!-- Start Header -->
   <p><strong>Admission Application - Basic Info</strong></p>           
    <div width="100%" height="5%" name="Applnbr" name="Applnbr">Application Nbr &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;<span id="Application_Id">#NEW</span>
 <input type="hidden" name="Appnbr" id="Appnbr" value=""/>
    </div>
    <!-- End Header-->
    <!-- Strat of First Div-->
 <div class="columnsContainer">
     <!-- Left Div Start-->
     <!-- Other Information Field Starts-->
    <div class="leftColumn">
     <div>
             <label id="doblbl" style="margin-left:10px;">Date Of Birth:<label style="margin-left:50px;"></label>
              <input id="dob" name="dob" type="text" value="">
             </label>
         </div></br>
         <div>          
             <label id="MMFnamelbl" style="margin-left:10px;">Mother's Maiden Name:</br>
              <label style="margin-left:10px;">*First name:</label><label style="margin-left:50px;"></label>
              <input id="MMFname" name="MMFname" type="text" value=""  style="margin-left:10px;" >
             </label>
         </div></br>
         <div>
             <label id="MMLnamelbl" style="margin-left:10px;">*Last name:<label style="margin-left:50px;"></label>
              <input id="MMLname" name="MMLname" type="text" value=""  style="margin-left:10px;" >
             </label>
         </div></br>
         <div>
             <label id="passport_numberlbl" style="margin-left:10px;">*Passport Number:<label style="margin-left:10px;"></label>
              <input id="passport_number" name="passport_number" type="text" value=""  style="margin-left:10px;" >
             </label>
            </div></br>
            <div>
             <label id="Place_of_Issuelbl" style="margin-left:10px;">*Place of issue:<label style="margin-left:30px;"></label>
              <input id="Place_of_Issue" name="Place_of_Issue" type="text" value=""  style="margin-left:10px;" >
             </label>
            </div></br>
            <div>
                <label id="Issue_datelbl" style="margin-left:10px;">*Issue Date:<label style="margin-left:50px;"></label>
              <input id="Issue_date" name="Issue_date" type="text" value=""  style="margin-left:10px;margin-top:10px;">
             </label>
            </div></br>
            <div>
                <label id="Passport_expiry_datelbl" style="margin-left:10px;">*Expiry:<label style="margin-left:70px;"></label>
              <input id="Passport_expiry_date" name="Passport_expiry_date" type="text" value=""  style="margin-left:10px;">
             </label>
            </div>
          </div>   
          <div class="rightColumn" style="width:50%">*Gender:
            <input checked="checked" name="Gender" type="radio" value="M" />Male
            <input name="Gender" type="radio" value="F" />Female
            </br> </br>*Nationality:
            <select name="Nationality" id="Nationality">
              <option value="UAE">UAE</option>
              <option value="ARE" selected>ARE</option>
    <option value="USA">USA</option>
    <option value="IND">IND</option>
            </select>
               </br></br>*Country Of Residency:
             <select name="Residency_country" id="Residency_country" onclick ="disableNational_ID();">
                    <option selected="selected" value="UAE">UAE</option>
                    <option value="ARE">ARE</option>
                    <option value="USA">USA</option>
     <option value="IND">IND</option>
                </select>
              </br></br>*National Id:
    <!--  <label id="Emirateslbl" style="margin-left:70px;">*National Id:</label> -->
              <input id="Emirates_Id" name="Emirates_Id" type="text" value=""  style="margin-left:10px;" >
              </br></br>*Marital Status:
             <select name="marital_status" id="marital_status">
    <!-- Dropdown will be filled from Xlatitem table -->
                     :%bind(:3);
                </select>            
            </br> </br> *Regional Preference:
             <select name="religious" id="religious">
    <!-- Dropdown will be filled from Religious table -->
                     :%bind(:4);
                </select>
          </div>
        <!-- Phone Entry table ends-->
  <table  id="phone" width="100%" name="phone">
   <tr>
    <td colspan="5" bgcolor="#5C85B3">Phone</td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <th>Type</td>
    <th>Country Code</th>
    <th>*Phone</th>
    <th>Preferred</th>
    <th>Add/Delete</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>
    <select name="phntype" id="phntype" style="width:50%">
    <!-- Phone Types -->
    %bind(:6);
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="cntrycde" id="cntrycde" value="">
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="text" name="phone_no" id="phone_no" value="">
    </td>
    <td>
    <input type="hidden" name="prefferd" value="NO">
    <input type="checkbox" name="preferred" id="preferred" value="N" onchange ="changeCheckBox();">
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="button" value="+" class="add">
         <input type="button" value="-" class="delete">
       </td>
   </tr>
  </table>
  <p></p>
  <!-- Phone Entry table ends-->
  <!-- Footer Of The Page-->
    <footer>*How do you Learn about side:</label> 
      <select name="source" id="source">
    <option selected="selected" value="internet">Internet</option>
    <option value="Media">Media</option>
    <option value="Newspaper">Newspaper</option>
   </select>
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit And Next" style="float:right">
  </footer>
  <!-- Footer Ends-->
 </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: i can use this in the tablestyle.css but there is some media screen on tableresponsive.css .But that properties is globally declare for all table since the datepicker has internally a table so its utilising that properties so in that CSS how we can use this above properties to restrict the usage of CSS propeties to be inherit

Comment: not its not working can u share me the demo to understand better

Comment: if you decrease the browser width then u can analyse the problem that means its taking the tableresponsive.css file and the tabular format change to a hudge grid of total no of day in the month .So i request you to please decrease the browser width and see the problem and give me a solution on this .Thanks

Comment: I am updating your code only but still the issue is not resolved.

Comment: your css is messed up

Comment: Sorry For my CSS actually the requirement is like the data in the phone table will come row wise and calender is shown as it is while shrink the volume of browser.Along with the add and delete row has to work .

Comment: " row wise " ?, the browser doesn't got a volume is not a 3d shape

Comment: give me ur mail id so that i can send u the image what is required

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use table with ID selector.

```
table#phone {
    /* your css styling code here */
}
```

Comment: not its not working can u share me the demo to understand better can u show me the demo .